# Python type comparison table

Tags: python, python-3.x

PHP has ['PHP type comparison tables'](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) is there anything like that for Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here (also included image below):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSS8R.jpg

From https://twitter.com/ngkabra/status/449904315012878337[image]

Comment: Sorry it took two years :)

Comment: I would like to add that 0.0 == False.

Comment: Furthermore, of course, `float('nan') != float('nan')` -- so the diagonal is "broken" in some places.

Answer (score 4):

Python is strongly typed; such a table is not required except between basic numeric types and basic string types. For numeric types, they are coerced to `long` (in 2.x) or `float` as required. For string types, things are not as simple and so `unicode` (in 2.x) should be used where possible.

```
>>> 3 > 2.4
True
>>> 'a' < u'あ'
True
>>> u'a' < 'あ'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comparison across incompatible types in 2.x will not act as you expect.

```
>>> 2 < '3'
True
>>> 3 < '2'
True
```

Comparison across incompatible types in 3.x will fail.

```
3>> 2 < '3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()
```

Comment: Because of comparisons like you pointed out, or comparing int to methods (because brackets were omited) or plain old 0 == False, and other comparison nuances make python in my books not a strong typed language. Interestingly it appears Assert statements will assist in catching such gotchas early on: "Assertions are particularly useful in Python because of Python's powerful and flexible dynamic typing system." - http://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively . 

Looking back my question it was not specific enough so I apologize for that and appreciate your response.

Comment: "Python is dynamically typed. The Python compiler is blissfully unaware of the types used in a program, and all type checking is done at run time." - http://python-history.blogspot.ca/2009/02/pythons-use-of-dynamic-typing.html